# How to load virtualbox video kernel module?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a virtual quantal (12.10) Ubuntu machine. Upon starting, it says in it its `boot.log`

```
 Loading VirtualBox video kernel module                                [fail]
```

What is this component and do I need it if I only want to ssh the virtual machine anyway. And for completeness sake, how would I fix it?